# Is it possible to copy a file into a zip archive?

Tags: command-line, zip

I want to copy a file into a ZIP or JAR archive.

Is that possible? If so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use -m to import a file to a ZIP archive.

I found this on StackOverflow maybe it helps you.
[How to move a file in to zip uncompressed, with zip cmd tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730747/how-to-move-a-file-in-to-zip-uncompressed-with-zip-cmd-tool/3731813#3731813)

But be careful it deletes the source file after it adds it to the archive.
See the link for more details.

**UPDATE**

Instructions from this site. http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm.
`-m` moves the specified files into the ZIP archive; actually, this deletes the target directories/files after making the specified ZIP archive.

If a directory becomes empty after removal of the files, the directory is also removed. No deletions are done until `zip` has created the archive without errors. This is useful for conserving disk space, but is potentially dangerous so it is recommended to use it in combination with `-T` to test the archive before removing all input files.

`zip -m yourfile zip.file`

Comment: i tried cp -m q.txt archive.zip !!!**not working

Answer (score 2):

**for jar extension you can use jar command as the following :

```
jar -uf file.jar newFile
```

**OR you can extract file from jar extension as following :

```
jar -xf file.jar fileToBeExtract
```

Have Fun :)